# Copay Log in Problem

Tags: copay

I bought a new phone and when I enter the account recovery phrase and password it tells me it is incorrect, is there any way I can contact someone at copay to help me log on?

Comment: You can try opening an issue here: https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues. However, if your recovery information is noted down incorrectly, there is little anyone can do to help you

Answer (score 1):

Official BitPay/Copay support can be reached here:
https://help.bitpay.com/requestHelp

Below are a few tips you can try to make the 12 word recovery phrase work:

- Are you sure that the recovery phrase was written in the correct order?
- Did you use all lowercase letters and no punctuation?
- Did you add a password to your recovery phrase?
- [Do you have the QR code or text/file backup?](https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003004363-I-lost-my-wallet-or-changed-my-phone-What-can-I-do-to-restore-my-wallet-)
- Did you separate each word with a single space (no commas or any other punctuation)?

Please also ensure that your words are all contained in the following list of possible words:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt